# Sequelize returning dates with wrong time

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, datetime, sequelize.js

The database and node are set as -02:00 timezone.

When I save a register, using sequelize, it saves the register with the right date and time in its date fields. For example, if I save a register with the field moment set as '2017-01-15T23:59:59-0200' and look in the database via MySQL Workbench I will see 2017-01-16 00:00:00 in the respective column.

I can even correctly find registers and filter by date and time.

But the value returned by a find operation in the field is '2017-01-16T01:59:59.000Z', meaning it was added two hours to the answer.

How could I retrive the correct date and time from MySQL using Sequelize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by overhiding String.toJSON:

```
Date.prototype.toJSON = function(){ return this.toLocaleString(); }
```

Comment: Oh gosh, I searched everything and never found something like this. Does this have any downside?

Comment: Where do you put it?